# Using a timer to hide a banner that is activated by something else?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I have the following code which basically displays a green bar whenever the user uploads some data successfully. (rendered={!uploadStatus})

```
<apex:outputPanel id="outerPanel">          
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!uploadStatus}">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!resetStatus}"  rerender="outerPanel" />
            <div class="demo-only" style="height: 4rem;">
                <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
                    <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_success" role="alert">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Success</span>
                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-success slds-m-right_small slds-no-flex slds-align-top" title="Description of icon when needed">
                        <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_small" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#success" />
                        </svg>
                        </span>
                    <div class="slds-notify__content">
                            <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small ">Success! Data was saved</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

it currently supports the user clicking on it

```
event="onclick" action="{!resetStatus}"
```

which basically calls the apex function

```
public void resetStatus(){
    uploadStatus = false;
}
```

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to have a timer instead which can reset the status so it just disappears after some time period (maybe 3 seconds). I'm not sure if this would require a change controller-side, or a change by adding a script or if SF has some native thing built in (my impression is no)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use an apex:actionPoller for this:

```
<apex:actionPoller interval="5" action="{!resetStatus}"  rerender="outerPanel" />
```

This will cause the system to display the message for five seconds, and then call resetStatus, at which point the outerPanel will rerender, and the message will disappear. Please note that interval must be at least 5 seconds. If you need a smaller window than that, you can use an actionFunction:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="resetStatusMessage" action="{!resetStatus}" reRender="outerPanel" />
<script>
setTimeout(resetStatusMessage, 2500 /* desired milliseconds */ );
</script>
```

By placing this inside the `outerPanel`, this method will only be called while there is a message displayed.

Other pure client-side options are also possible, but would require a bit more work to correct from your current design.

Comment: Woo it works! Thank you :) Small thing: the OuterPanel in the second block starts with a single quote, and should be a double, and it should be a small O instead of a big O at the start (I got stuck for a bit).

Comment: @user49458 Yeah, those were just typos. I'm glad you were able to get it worked out!